# Print in bold on a terminal

Tags: java, terminal, ansi-escape

How can I print output in bold using printf? `"[1m testing bold"` does not do anything.

```
String format = "%-20s %-15s %-20s %-15s %-10s";

System.out.printf(format, "Name", "Group_name", "Java_Prof_Level", "Cpr_Nr", "Gender", "[1m testing bold");
```

Comment: You need to make the bold argument first, not last.

Comment: see also https://github.com/fusesource/jansi

Comment: @Malik does not work due to the format "[1m testing bold" is printed as txt

Comment: This must have been a mega duplicate in 2015. Why wasn't there any effort to find the canonical question? E.g. "`[1m`" is a dead giveaway that it is about [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (e.g., (virtual) terminals). Visitors from search engines may end up shipwrecked here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot print bold with Java `System.out`. It just streams to the standard output stream so, in principle, it is unformatted text only.

However, some software packages interpret special character sequences (the so-called ANSI escape sequences) to allow formatting.

Note that ANSI escape sequences start with an escape character, so you need to add that to your string also. (Try `"\u001B[1m I am bold"` or `"\033[0;1m" + "I am bold"`.)

Most Unix terminals interpret ANSI escape sequences by default. In old DOS times, you needed to use **ANSI.SYS** for the escape sequences to work.

In Windows and the Eclipse terminal the codes do not work.

Answer (score 7):

This really depends on what kind of console is being used. For IDEs like [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) and [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), I'm not sure if you can affect the font. But for most terminals, the following escape character works:

```
String textInBold = "Java_Prof_Level";
System.out.print("\033[0;1m" + textInBold);
```

Comment: Thank you, just tried: "\033[0;1m". It does not work in Netbeans

Answer (score 0):

I found this. It is for Epson ECS/POS.

```
string ESC = "\u001B";
string GS = "\u001D";
string InitializePrinter = ESC + "@";
string BoldOn = ESC + "E" + "\u0001";
string BoldOff = ESC + "E" + "\0";
string DoubleOn = GS + "!" + "\u0011";  // 2x sized text (double-high + double-wide)
string DoubleOff = GS + "!" + "\0";

printJob.Print(InitializePrinter);
printJob.PrintLine("Here is some normal text.");
printJob.PrintLine(BoldOn + "Here is some bold text." + BoldOff);
printJob.PrintLine(DoubleOn + "Here is some large text." + DoubleOff);
```

First page of the PDF document: [here is a reference link](https://download.delfi.com/SupportDL/Epson/Manuals/TM-T20/Manuals/Epson%20TM-T20%20ESC-POS%20Quick%20Reference%20Guide%20.pdf)

I must use "" before the command. Otherwise it doesn't work:

```
oStream.print("" + (char)27 + (char)97 + (char)1); // For centering text
```

Comment: can you add some reference links for escape characters, it will be helpful to find other escape characters too

Comment: The link is broken: *"404 - File or directory not found."*