# Integer / Double value

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code which says whether you are cheapskate, patron, etc depending on the amount you donate.

This is the code:

```
public class Donor {

   public static void main(String [] args) {

  System.out.println(" % java Donor");

 System.out.print("Enter the amount of a contribution:    $");

  java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

 double money = sc.nextInt();

 if ( money >= 0) {

    if ( money < 15 ) {

      System.out.println("Cheapskate!");

    }

    if ( money >= 15 && money < 200) {

      System.out.print("Friend!");

    }

    if ( money >= 200 && money < 1000) {

      System.out.println("Supporter!");

    }

    if ( money >= 1000 && money < 10000) {

   System.out.println("Patron!");

    }

    if (money >= 10000) {

      System.out.println("Benefactor!");

    }

  } else {

    System.out.println("You have an entered an invalid value!");

  }



 }

 }
```

The problem is that it only accepts integers. If I enter 90.34 it won't accept it and will fail. 
How can i fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined your input variable money as double but you are reading an int from scanner here:

```
 double money = sc.nextInt();
```

Use Scanner [nextDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()) to read double input instead of an int.

```
 double money = sc.nextDouble();
```

Comment: I have another question. how can I make the first line % Java Donor both bold and underlined. Also how can I make the input be bold? @JunedAhsan

Comment: You cannot print to Standard.out in bold. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109678/java-print-in-bold

Comment: @JackStew Your original question is answered. If you find it useful then accept the answer. For any other unrelated question, you can always post a different question to get broader exposure.