# Java bolding and underlining output

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I have this code

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter any sentence.");
    String line = keyboard.nextLine();
    String s1 = line;
    String[] sp = s1.split(" ");
    System.out.println("second word is " + sp[1]);
}
```

It prints out second word. So if you input

> hi i am practicing java

it will output

> The second word is i

Is there any way or method to make it print out `sp[1]` to look bold and underlined or anything so it sticks out? The output would be

> The second word is ***I***

Comment: The answer to this question has been given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109678/java-print-in-bold

Comment: @AntonioRomeo If you feel that the question already has an answer then please flag this one as a **duplicate**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ANSI escape sequences before the string you want to output. This will work on most linux like os.

```
System.out.println("second word is \033[0;1m" + sp[1]);
```

Comment: How do i stop the bolding say i want to add more words after sp[1]+ "."

Comment: @Javabeginner you could send a wrong escape sequence. e.g.         `System.out.println("second word is \033[0;1m" + textInBold + "\033[0;0m" + textInBold);`

Answer (score 1):

It largely depends upon the capabilities of the system that you are outputting to. In most cases, you will only have plain-text output. On occasion, [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) or [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) will be supported by the terminal/console output. In particular, the bash terminal and Windows 10 (threshold 2) terminal support ANSI escape codes.

Using [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/), most versions of windows can be customized to support ANSI escape codes.

In a few limited situations, you may have a specialized markup language available through the console.

Comment: You can do this, but there's a java library that has all of these built in. [Source] (https://github.com/fusesource/jansi)

Comment: @CarterBrainerd It looks like a good library. There are many obscure but useful libraries available on github and not all of them are spread by word-of-mouth. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just tested on Intellij and it works. This one is for underling:

```
    System.out.println("second word is \033[0;4m" + sp);
```

Comment: This works for me, in my case `"\033[1;4mThe-String-To-Format\033[0m"` makes the text bold and underlines it.