# Bold text while pasting in Gmail composer

Tags: gmail, html-email, plaintext, text-formatting

I have to copy some text from a plain text file into Gmail's mail composer and make some parts of that text bold. I can obviously boldface those specific parts manually after pasting it to the composer. But is there a way to do this automatically such that when I copy that content to the Gmail composer those parts is already bold.

For example, here's the plain text to be copied to Gmail:

> **Breaking News:** Elon Musk just invaded Mars.

I would normally copy this text to Gmail's composer and manually bolden the part **Breaking news**. But if the source would have been, say, MS Word file instead of a plain text file, Gmail would have boldfaced it for me.

Background: The reason I am looking for this is that the plain text file is an output of a simple Java program and I would just edit the Java program to give the necessary output that would handle boldfacing.

P.S: I have tried wrapping those parts with `<b>` tags like this:

```
<b>Breaking news </b>: Elon Musk just invaded Mars.
```

It didn't work. Gmail simply prints the  tag itself with my content.

Comment: anwered here I guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109678/java-print-in-bold

Comment: @so_what not really. I doubt Gmail cares about ANSI escape sequences, but if you're creating a HTML email, then you can format it in lots of different ways.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to send the message to the Gmail composer? So that we can know if that will accept HTML tags such as `<b>`

Comment: @so_what That question speaks about printing in bold. My case is writing to a file in bold.

Comment: @JulesDupont I don't use any code to send the message to Gmail composer. It's just a manual copy-paste.

Comment: So your question actually has nothing to do with Java or file IO. It's just about having Gmail accept HTML.

Comment: Could you please provide (post) a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Kayaman and SergeyBrunov, I have updated my question!

Comment: What if you copy the text from a browser with the rendered HTML? If you're just copying the raw text, it'll be of type "text". Gmail doesn't know that you want it to interpret the text as HTML.

Comment: @Kayaman Yeah, that's a smart alternative I guess. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The [Sending Email  |  Gmail API  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) example may be used as the starting point with the addition, which is described below.

It is enough to prepare the message body (the value of the `htmlBody` variable) as the HTML document:

```
final MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

// From.
message.setFrom(...);

// To.
message.addRecipient(...);

// Subject.
message.setSubject(...);

// Body: HTML content.
message.setContent(htmlBody, "text/html");
```

Basic information on the HTML document formatting, in particular, on how to make a piece of text bold, please refer to [HTML Text Formatting](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp): see the `<b>` element.