# How can I print a message in bold using system.out on Eclipse console in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, console, output, bold

How can I print a message in bold using System.out.println() on Eclipse console in Java?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java, print in bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109678/java-print-in-bold)

Comment: The Eclipse console does not support any sort of highlighting (bold, colors, ...)

Answer (score 0):

System.out.print("\033[0;1m" + "your text");

Comment: Does not work on the Eclipse console which doesn't support this.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you can't as unformatted text is sent to the stdout. However, you can character-sequences that allow for such a thing -

```
public class TimepassBold {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.print("\u001B[1m This is bold text");
  }
}
```

I tried this in git bash and IntelliJ Idea, it works.
If you'd really like to colorize your logs, [have a look at this](https://dev.to/awwsmm/coloured-terminal-output-with-java-57l3).

Edit - Thanks Greg for correcting me. This won't work in Eclipse, it is simply just a terminal, nothing else.

Comment: That does not work on the Eclipse console.

Answer (score -1):

use log4j

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It'd be worthwhile to add in details about how one can use the framework to achieve what he needs (bold text on console).