# How can I write bold text in the console for Java?

Tags: java, blackjack

I am making a Blackjack program using Java, and I want to add bold text to it; however, I am having trouble knowing how to do that. Can anyone help?

I have tried to look up escape codes for it (I know they exist, I just don't remember them) on here and on the web, but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: see also [Print in bold on a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109678/print-in-bold-on-a-terminal#:~:text=(Try%20%22%5Cu001B%5B1m,%22I%20am%20bold%22%20.))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to write texts bold on console for IDEs like NetBeans and Eclipse

```
String boldText= "Java_Bold_Text";
System.out.print("\033[0;1m" + boldText);
```

Comment: Will this work in Windows?

Comment: Thank you! It took me a while to figure out how to use it, but it works! :)